# Rails vuejs get height of iframe element

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, iframe

I am using `vuejs` with `rails` webpacker and `turbolinks`. I want to calculate the correct height of the `iframe` element on the initial page load. Currently, I am getting the height of the element when I manually refresh the page, and when someone navigates from any other pages to the page where the `iframe` element is located, the height of the element is not calculated.

My `index.js` setup:

```js
Vue.use(TurbolinksAdapter);
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  const app = new Vue({
    el: '[data-behaviour="vue"]',
  });
});
```

My `preview.vue` where the `iframe` element is located.

```js
data() {
    return {
      frameHeight: '',
    };
  },
   computed: {
    computeHeight() {
      this.frameHeight =
        this.$refs.iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      this.computeHeight;
    });
  },
```

I have tried replacing the `mounted` hook with the `created` hook as well, and instead of listening for the `load` event I have tried listening for the `turbolinks:load` event as well. But it doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping the compute height code in nextTick like so:

```
data() {
    return {
      frameHeight: '',
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => { 
      window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        this.frameHeight =
          this.$refs.iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
      });
    })
  },
```

This should allow the elements to load before executing the code to grab height.

Comment: Probably don't need the eventListener in this case

Answer (score -1):

You won't need the eventListener when using nextTick. You can just do it like:

```
data() {
    return {
      frameHeight: '',
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => { 
      this.frameHeight = 
          this.$refs.iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
    });

  },
```

Comment: Yes you need it, without it the component is not rendered